How to retrieve parameter list binded to SYS_REFCURSOR from a stored procedure, what is the ODBC call i should use
I need to get column information of the result set via C++ code.
How to retrieve parameter list binded to SYS_REFCURSOR from a stored procedure, what is the ODBC call i should use. SQLProcedureColumns() api is only getting information about primitive parameter types, but not SYS_REFCURSOR parameters.
Below is the sample procedure I created to take input as file id and get column data for File size and file type.
Schema name is UserName
Table name is V_FILES
I am not able to get p_file_info and p_file_size cursor parameters by using SQLPocedureColumns() API, Please suggest how to retrieve cursor parameters.
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UserName.get_file_infocursor2 (
     p_file_id IN NUMBER,
     p_file_info OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
     p_file_size_info OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS BEGIN
 
    
OPEN p_file_info FOR
SELECT UserName.V_FILES.FILE_NAME, UserName.V_FILES.FILE_TYPE
FROM UserName.V_FILES
WHERE UserName.V_FILES.FILE_IID = p_file_id;

OPEN p_file_size_info FOR
SELECT UserName.V_FILES.PARENT_FOLDER_IID, UserName.V_FILES.TIME_STAMP
FROM UserName.V_FILES
WHERE UserName.V_FILES.FILE_IID = p_file_id;
  
 
 -- If the file is not found, raise an exception
     EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('file not found'); END;


I tried using SQLProcedureColumns API to retrieve all parameters but its only giving information about p_file_id but not about SUS_REFCURSOR parameters
